# 'Timeout Expired' error when buffer cache clean

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, sql-server-2005

I am going to sum up my problem first and then offer massive details and what I have already tried.

### Summary:

I have an internal winform app that uses Linq 2 Sql to connect to a local SQL Express database.  Each user has there own DB and the DB stay in sync through Merge Replication with a Central DB.  All DB's are SQL 2005(sp2or3).  We have been using this app for over 5 months now but recently our users are getting a  `Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

### Detailed:

The strange part is they get that in two differnt locations(*2 differnt LINQ Methods*) and only the first time they fire in a given time period(*~5mins*).

One LINQ method is pulling all records that match a FK ID and then Manipulating them to form a Heirarchy View for a TreeView.  The second is pulling all records that match a FK ID and dumping them into a DataGridView.  The only things I can find in common with the 2 are that the first IS an IEnumerable and the second converts itself from IQueryable -> IEnumerable -> DataTable...

I looked at the query's in Profiler and they 'seemed' normal.  They are not very complicated querys.  They are only pulling back 10 - 90 records, from one table.

Any thoughts, suggestions, hints whatever would be greatly appreciated.  I am at my wit's end on this....

---

```
public IList<CaseNoteTreeItem> GetTreeViewDataAsList(int personID)
{
    var myContext = MatrixDataContext.Create();

    var caseNotesTree =
        from cn in myContext.tblCaseNotes
        where cn.PersonID == personID
        orderby cn.ContactDate descending,
            cn.InsertDate descending
        select new CaseNoteTreeItem
        {
            CaseNoteID = cn.CaseNoteID,
            NoteContactDate = Convert.ToDateTime(cn.ContactDate).
                ToShortDateString(),
            ParentNoteID = cn.ParentNote,
            InsertUser = cn.InsertUser,
            ContactDetailsPreview = cn.ContactDetails.Substring(0, 75)
        };

    return caseNotesTree.ToList<CaseNoteTreeItem>();            
}
```

AND THIS ONE

```
public static DataTable GetAllCNotes(int personID)
{
    using (var context = MatrixDataContext.Create())
    {
        var caseNotes =
            from cn in context.tblCaseNotes
            where cn.PersonID == personID
            orderby cn.ContactDate
            select new
            {
                cn.ContactDate,
                cn.ContactDetails,
                cn.TimeSpentUnits,
                cn.IsCaseLog,
                cn.IsPreEnrollment,
                cn.PresentAtContact,
                cn.InsertDate,
                cn.InsertUser,
                cn.CaseNoteID,
                cn.ParentNote
            };

        return caseNotes.ToList().CopyLinqToDataTable();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT to show generated SQL

this is `GetTreeViewAsList(int personID)`

```
SELECT [t0].[CaseNoteID], [t0].[ParentNote] AS [ParentNoteID], CONVERT(DateTime,[t0].[ContactDate]) AS [value], [t0].[InsertUser], SUBSTRING([t0].[ContactDetails], 0 + 1, 75) AS [ContactDetailsPreview]
FROM [dbo].[tblCaseNotes] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[PersonID] = 123456
ORDER BY [t0].[ContactDate] DESC, [t0].[InsertDate] DESC
```

and this is `GetALlCaseNotes(int personID)`

```
SELECT [t0].[ContactDate], [t0].[ContactDetails], [t0].[TimeSpentUnits], [t0].[IsCaseLog], [t0].[IsPreEnrollment], [t0].[PresentAtContact], [t0].[InsertDate], [t0].[InsertUser], [t0].[CaseNoteID], [t0].[ParentNote]
FROM [dbo].[tblCaseNotes] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[PersonID] = 123456
ORDER BY [t0].[ContactDate]
```

Comment: Please show us the code, without this, it is very hard to reason about.

Comment: @Steven:  Okay but since it happens through 2 different code paths It will be a lot of code and I am not sure overly relevent but anything to try and solve this.

Comment: Try to create test application with the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem. When you have this, post this code.

Comment: @Steven: Posted Code.  I will put this code into a console app.  My concern though is that this error does not happen on all user systems.

Comment: Your linq queries look completely normal. When the call takes 5 minutes, how is the CPU utilization of the machine and the database server and how is the IO of that machine and the database server? You need to find out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Try pulling the generated SQL from the profiler and running it with a SQL client on the same server as the database you're connecting to. This may have nothing to do with LINQ.

Comment: @Steven: The call doesn't take 5 mins.  It errors out after, maybe, 30 seconds.  5 mins is how long the page has to be idle before it will happen again.

Comment: @Jake: Thanks but I have already done this and it runs fine.  What is strange is that I can run this from a computer fine if I point the method at the Central Server(SQL 2005 Standard) but from that same machine if I point it, immediately, at there local server(SQL 2005 Express) it will time out the first time it runs that query.

Comment: @Refracted Paladin - Are other queries running concurrently during this gap or is it basically the first time it gets any query after a 5 minute gap? Also what happens if you clear the caches with `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` and `dbcc freeproccache` will this cause it to happen?

Comment: @Martin Smith: None that I am aware of.  THe local SQL Express's existince is ONLY for this App. `dbcc dropcleanbuffers` This one causes the same thing.  Either **generated SQL** statement takes over 30 seconds to run at the local machine the first time it is run after running that statement OR waiting a specified amount of time.  Now how do I fix that I wonder and ***WHY*** does such a simple query take 34 seconds on a local DB.  See edit for SQL...

Comment: @Refracted Paladin It sounds like the query must do a lot of I/O. Do you have an index on PersonID in tblCaseNotes? If not maybe try adding one.

Comment: @Martin Smith:It is not currently indexed.  Any ideas on the Impact to our Merge Replication if I index a FK field like that?  Also, is that really my only course of action, to add an index, or is there other things I can try.  Tweaking the query, increasing the timeout, etc.  Just asking.  Thanks  for everthing!

Comment: Not really any sensible alternative. Both queries are doing a direct look up against PersonID and would be well served by an index. I've never used Merge Replication so can't answer that part. It is simply adding a new access path to the data rather than modifying the data so I can't see why it should make any difference to it.

Comment: Thanks,  I will have to look into the impact on Replication.  Doing a quick Execution Plan on these querys confirms what you are saying the following 
*`Missing Index Details from CaseNotesTimeoutQuerys.sql - mylocal\sqlexpress.MATRIX (WWCARES\pschaller (54))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 99.5556%.
`*

Comment: Cool. I'll make it into an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lack of an index on PersonId means that both of the problem queries need to do a full table scan. When the data is not in the buffer already this means a lot of I/O which explains why you notice it particularly the first time they fire in a given time period.

Adding the following index should resolve it.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_tblCaseNotes_PersonID ON tblCaseNotes (PersonID)
```

Comment: Awsomesauce, thanks!  Now I just need to figure out the impact of doing this in our Merge Replication Topology.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit a long shot, but perhaps the problem is not one of performance, but of connectivity. When your SQL Server configured to use Named Pipes instead of the default protocol, it can take a long time before the .NET SqlClient can establish a connection, because it tries to connect using the default protocol order.

You can read more about this, [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/adonet/sqlclient-default-protocol-order)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  I verified that the default protocol order is in conjunction with what your link recommends.  Still no dice...